# gcc __builtin_expect doesn't seem to generate a correct code

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, built-in

The following two code snippets produces exactly the same assembly code, even though branches are enclosed with different branch predictions.

Let's say that we have **test0.c**

```
#define likely(x)       __builtin_expect((x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)     __builtin_expect((x), 0)

int bar0();
int bar1();
int bar2();
int bar3();

int foo(int arg0) {
  if (likely(arg0 > 100)) {
    return bar0();
  } else if (likely(arg0 < -100)) {
    return bar1();
  } else if (likely(arg0 > 0)) {
    return bar2();
  } else {
    return bar3();
  }
}
```

and **test1.c**

```
#define likely(x)       __builtin_expect((x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)     __builtin_expect((x), 0)

int bar0();
int bar1();
int bar2();
int bar3();

int foo(int arg0) {
  if (unlikely(arg0 > 100)) {
    return bar0();
  } else if (unlikely(arg0 < -100)) {
    return bar1();
  } else if (unlikely(arg0 > 0)) {
    return bar2();
  } else {
    return bar3();
  }
}
```

As you can see by comparing two snippets, these two have different branch predictions for each branch (likely() vs. unlikely()).

However, when it is compiled from a linux box(ubuntu 12.04 32bit, gcc 4.6.3). These two sources produce virtually same outputs.

```
$gcc  -c -S -o test0.s test0.c
$gcc  -c -S -o test1.s test1.c
$ diff test0.s test1.s
1c1
<   .file   "test0.c"
---
>   .file   "test1.c"
```

If anyone can explain this, it will be a big help.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The two files you've posted are identical -- I assume this isn't what you've really done.

Compile with `-O2` or higher, you need to turn on optimisation. This should then generate different code.

Answer (score 0):

I did some measurements on ARM7 (Allwinner sun71 A20), and with gcc 6.3 (-O3) and there was no performance difference between #likely and #unlikely even though it was clear from other tests that taking a branch was more expensive than not taking it, even in the case of perfect branch prediction.